# Rabbit MQ pattern for dealing with events and work for multiple instances of a consumer service

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, messaging

I would like to broadcast out an event, "new user create" as an example, that any service can be notified about.  In my case this event kicks off work for one of my services.  I would like to be able to add many instances of this service and not have each service be notified of this event.  What I would like is that the event is created and added to a work type queue for this one service, but the event can be subscribed to by any service.  What is the best way to do this with Rabbit MQ?

Comment: rabbitmq can not automatically route the tasks you have to write a custom logic to route the tasks to your instances.